# Validate Structure Mandatory Attributes in OutSystems

Tags: validation, outsystems

I have a variable with structure type. This structure has some mandatory attributes.

How can I validate if this variable has all mandatory attributes filled out correctly?

Do it manually is not an available option.

Comment: From where do you receive the structure? Is it a form?

Comment: Is it a simple or complex structure?

Comment: It's a complex structure and is not a form. A receive the structure from a REST API that my application expose.

Comment: As Miguel is saying in the comment bellow, there's no way to validate that automatically unless it's in a form

Answer (score 0):

Unless the origin of the data in the structure is a screen Form, whereby you can set the appropriate Inputs' **Mandatory** attribute to True (thus automatically enforcing that something is typed in on submit), the only other way is to check it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an invisible EditRecords widget and make it the validation parent of all the fields in your struct. Then, make sure your summit button has client side validation, and make sure the fields you want to check are actually mandatory on the struct. Good luck!

Comment: There is no EditRecords or submit buttons. I want to validate a structure from a REST API. The structure is a variable and cannot be on any page.